# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\data\\ISIC_0025924.jpg'

Tags: python, anaconda

i am trying to access the HAM DATASET which i placed in a folder named data but it brings an error(FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\data\ISIC_0025924.jpg') when i try to access it. what could be the problem? [ERROR PIC1[][1]][1]here is he code

```
tfms = get_transforms(flip_vert=True)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_df(r"/data/", df, fn_col=1, suffix='.jpg', label_col=7, 
ds_tfms=tfms, size=224, bs=16)
data.normalize(imagenet_stats)
```

HERE is the link to the other error image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKf9g.png

Comment: The data folder has two sub folders init namely HAM10000_images_part_1 and  HAM10000_images_part_2 and other excel metadata

Answer (score 0):

Try `r"./data/"`, you seem to refer to a folder from the root of your filesystem, instead of a local folder